# Get info and change with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem. I have object name: 'Коля', age: 30, I need to create ul where this info will be. After that I need to edit this information onclcik. On edit (span) I want to create one input and one button. Input should have this information name and age. Currently I am getting it After I get it, I should have an option to change it. So when I click on the change button, it should save my changes and this should be for each line of li.

```js
var products = [
 {name: 'Коля', age: 30},
 {name: 'Вася', age: 40},
 {name: 'Петя', age: 50},
];

var ul = document.createElement("ul");

for( var i = 0; i < products.length; i++ ){
 var li = document.createElement("li");
 var span = document.createElement("span");
 span.innerHTML = products[i].name + " " + products[i].age + " " + "Edit";
 span.classList.add("newClass");

 li.addEventListener("click", editInfo);
 li.appendChild(span);
 ul.appendChild(li);
 document.body.appendChild(ul);
}

 var inputAge = document.createElement("input");

function editInfo(){
 var button = document.createElement("button");
 button.innerHTML = "Change";

 inputAge.value = this.children.innerHTML;

 document.body.appendChild(inputAge);
 document.body.appendChild(button);

}
```

Comment: Try `this.children[0].innerHTML`. **this.children** will return a collection/node list of elements.

Comment: @NewToJS and how i should get it?

Comment: As explained above... by targeting a specific element from the collection returned [**JsFiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/732hmeo1/)

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to add UL to the document each time.

`document.body.appendChild(ul)` - should be outside the for loop.

`li.addEventListener("click", editInfo)` - should be changed, also study about event loops concepts in javascript

Find the proper code below and write your own 'change' function.

```
var products = [
{name: 'Коля', age: 30},
{name: 'Вася', age: 40},
{name: 'Петя', age: 50},
];

var ul = document.createElement("ul");

for( var i = 0; i < products.length; i++ ){
var li = document.createElement("li");
var span1 = document.createElement("span");
var span2 = document.createElement("span");
span1.innerHTML = products[i].name + " " + products[i].age;
span2.innerHTML = " Edit";
span1.classList.add("newClass");

li.addEventListener("click", function(){return editInfo(this);});
li.appendChild(span1);
li.appendChild(span2);
ul.appendChild(li);
}

document.body.appendChild(ul);

var inputAge = document.createElement("input");

function editInfo(el){
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerHTML = "Change";
console.log(el)
inputAge.value = el.children[0].innerHTML;

document.body.appendChild(inputAge);
document.body.appendChild(button);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one example of how to do what you need.

I've added comment in detail.

If I've misunderstood your question or any question, please let me know.

```js
// preparation
var products = [
    { name: 'Коля', age: 30 },
    { name: 'Вася', age: 40 },
    { name: 'Петя', age: 50 },
];

var ul = document.createElement("ul");
document.body.appendChild(ul);

var inputAge = document.createElement("input");
// set input type as number
inputAge.setAttribute("type", "number");
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerHTML = "Change";
inputAge.style.display = "none";
button.style.display = "none";

document.body.appendChild(inputAge);
document.body.appendChild(button);
// preparation done

// set products to li
for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {

    var li = document.createElement("li");
    setContent(li, products[i])
    ul.appendChild(li);
}

// function to set one li's content
function setContent(el, obj) {
    // rebuild the span
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerHTML = obj.name + " " + obj.age + " " + "Edit";
    // bind edit event handler
    span.addEventListener("click", editInfo);
    // reset li's content
    el.innerHTML = '';
    el.appendChild(span);
}

// what edit do
function editInfo(e) {
    // retrieve name&age
    var arr = e.target.innerHTML.split(' ');
    var name = arr[0].trim();
    var age = parseInt(arr[1]);
    // set text value to input
    inputAge.value = age;
    // show input and change button
    inputAge.style.display = "block";
    button.style.display = "block";
    
    // set change button here for easily get name
    button.onclick = function() {
      setContent(e.target, {
          name: name,
          age: inputAge.value
    })
    // hide input and button
    inputAge.style.display = "none";
    button.style.display = "none";
};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery for DOM Manipulation:

```js
var products = [{
        name: 'Коля',
        age: 30
    },
    {
        name: 'Вася',
        age: 40
    },
    {
        name: 'Петя',
        age: 50
    }
];

loadList();

function loadList() {
    var listItem = '';

    for (var key in products) {
        listItem +=
            "<li onClick=editListData('" +
            products[key].name +
            "','" +
            products[key].age +
            "','" +
            key +
            "')>" +
            products[key].name +
            ' ,' +
            products[key].age +
            '</li>';
    }
    $('.userDataList').html(listItem);
}

function editListData(name, age, key) {
    var inputContainer = $('.inputContainer');
    var in_put = `<div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="usr">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" value='${name}' class="form-control" id="usr" name="usr">
                      </div><br/>
                      <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="age">Age:</label>
                  <input type="text" value='${age}' class="form-control" id="age" name="age">
                      </div><br/>
                      <button type="button" onClick="updateData('${key}')"class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
                       </div>`;
    inputContainer.html(in_put);
}

function updateData(key) {
    var name = $('#usr').val();
    var age = $('#age').val();
    products[key] = {
        name: name,
        age: age
    };
    loadList();
    $('.inputContainer').html('');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myListData">
<ul class="userDataList"></ul>
</div>
<div class="inputContainer">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Knowing I'm late to the party,

I have used `jQuery` to achieve what you want.

Instead of manipulating the DOM to edit, the user edits the object in the background and then upon pressing `Change` button, the view gets updated.

I have used `data-product-index` to keep track of the index within the array on the element itself.

---

```js
var products = [{
    name: 'Коля',
    age: 30
  },
  {
    name: 'Вася',
    age: 40
  },
  {
    name: 'Петя',
    age: 50
  },
];

showProducts();

function showProducts() {
  // Remove old #product UL if exists
  $('#products').remove();
  // Append UL
  $('body').append('<ul id="products"></ul>');
  // Iterate over products
  products.forEach((elem, i) => {
    // Using ES6 Template Literals
    $('ul').append(`<li><span data-product-index="${i}" onclick='editInfo(this);'>${elem.name} ${elem.age} Edit</span></li>`);
  });
}

function editInfo(elem) {
  // Remove old edit field
  $('#editField').remove();
  // Append an edit div
  $('body').append(`<div id="editField">Editing Item: ${$(elem).data('product-index')}<br>Name:<br><input type="text" id="editInputName"/><br>Age:<br><input type="number" id="editInputAge"/><br><button id="editButton">Change</button></div>`);

  $('button').on('click', (e) => {
    products[$(elem).data('product-index')].name = $('#editInputName').val();
    products[$(elem).data('product-index')].age = $('#editInputAge').val();

    console.log(products[$(elem).data('product-index')]);
    // Remove click event
    $('button').off('click');
    // Remove edit field
    $('#editField').remove();

    // Show updated object
    showProducts();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```